# Flask doesn't render any image

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application where I need to render an image created by Pygal (a visualization library).So I plan to give users access to this created image at an endpoint `/viz`

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/viz")
def viz():
    img_url = '/home/souvik/PycharmProjects/ServiceHandler/static/histo_visual.svg'
    return render_template('app.html', image_url=img_url)
```

Below is the **app.html** file

```
<html>
<head>
     <title> Metric Visualization</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
         <p>Bar Chart</p>
         <object type="image/svg+xml" data="{{image_url}}">
         </object>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my project structure

[image]

As you can see the file **histo_visual.svg** does exists in the static folder.So when I run the program and try to access the `/viz` endpoint, I get the below error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2018 15:08:59] "GET /viz HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2018 15:08:59] "GET /home/souvik/PycharmProjects/ServiceHandler/static/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Below is the page displayed

[image]

Why does it give `404` not found error when the file exists?I have even gone to the directory and run the file through a browser and it shows me the expected visualization.Then what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're accessing the image through a web server, the image url must be relative to the web root. You're using the full file path of the image, but this is not accessible to the application in a web context.

Flask has a neat way of generating URLs for static files:

```
@app.route("/viz")
def viz():
    img_url = url_for('static', filename='histo_visual.svg')
    return render_template('app.html', image_url=img_url)
```

or alternatively, simply render this directly in the Jinja template:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="{{ url_for('static', filename='histo_visual.svg') }}">
         </object>
```

Comment: thanks!I never realized that my path url wouldn't make any sense from a server's perspective :)