# Python Flask - How to dynamically handle image and folder generation

Tags: python, flask

I got some understanding of how to create a webpage using Python Flask to display a png image from these webpages:

- [Where does flask look for image files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207761/where-does-flask-look-for-image-files)
- [Flask doesn't render any image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750711/flask-doesnt-render-any-image)
- [Change static folder from config in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346486/change-static-folder-from-config-in-flask)

This is my Python Flask code:

```
template_dir = "/home/maxloo/pyrest/"
static_dir = "/home/maxloo/pyrest/static"
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir, static_url_path=static_dir)

@app.route("/petri/<uuid>")
def getPetriFile(uuid):
  dirPath = template_dir + "temp/workdir/" + uuid + "/petri/"
  dotPath = dirPath + "LATEST"
  petriFolder = static_dir + "/temp/workdir/" + uuid + "/petri/"
  if not os.path.exists(petriFolder):
    Path(petriFolder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  petriPath = petriFolder + "LATEST.png"
  templatePetriPath = "/temp/workdir/" + uuid + "/petri/LATEST.png"
  return render_template("image.html", user_image = templatePetriPath)
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image">
  <object type="image/png" data="{{ user_image }}">
  </object>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the web page could not display the image.  Can anyone help?  The images I use and the folders that contain them are dynamically generated.  Only the template parent directory is static.

I've amended my code to include `static_url_path`, but it still did not display the image.

This is the output of running the `tree` command:

```
┌─[20220629-08:57:28]   [maxloo@:~/pyrest/static]
└─[0] <> tree
.
├── LATEST.png
└── temp
    └── workdir
        └── 28d023bd-84e7-445a-8488-1e8aeb1fd50a
            └── petri
                └── LATEST.png
4 directories, 2 files
```

I've even tried this Python Flask code:

```
template_dir = "/home/maxloo/pyrest/"
static_dir = "/home/maxloo/pyrest/static/"
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir, static_url_path=static_dir)
app.static_url_path = static_dir
for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules('static'):
  app.url_map._rules.remove(rule)
app.url_map._rules_by_endpoint['static'] = []
app.view_functions["static"] = None
app.add_url_rule(static_dir + "LATEST.png",
  endpoint='static',
  view_func=app.send_static_file)

@app.route("/petri/<uuid>")
def getPetriFile(uuid):
  petriPath = static_dir + "LATEST.png"
  return render_template("image.html", user_image = static_dir)
```

I've left out most of the code in `def getPetriFile(uuid):` because they are only required for the generation of the dynamic image file LATEST.png.

Comment: `template_folder` is used for templates or HTML/Jinja Files. Where as `static_folder` is used for serving static assets like javascript, css, images or any other static files. So you need to create your dynamic folder within static folder so it can be served.

Comment: @GodWin, I've changed my code to include `static_url_path`, but it still did not work...

Comment: @GodWin, I do not use config.py.  I could not find any config.py file in my root folder for the application.

Comment: you create folder dynamically but you have to also put image in this folder. later you create path to image but this image may not exist in this folder. Did you check if you have image in this folder on disk?

Comment: @furas, I've added the output of running the `tree` command in my post.  The image file is generated successfully.

Comment: you could use `print()` to see if you have correct values in variables. And you could use `os.path.exists` to check if it can find file when you run code. Maybe you don't have this file when you run code but it adds it later.

Comment: and you should check if you can open this `LATEST.png` in any image browser - maybe file is broken and web browser can't display it.

Comment: check path in you new code - you send `user_image = static_dir` - so you send path to folder but you have to send path to image `user_image = "/LATEST.png"` or `user_image = "/temp/workdir/28d023bd-84e7-445a-8488-1e8aeb1fd50a.petri/LATEST.png"`. Maybe see directly in `HTML` in browser what path you generated.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it always needs path with prefix `/static` - like. `"/static/LATEST.png"`  because flask may use `/static` to recognize path to image and use some built-in `router("/static/<path>")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but all problem can be because `Flask` has two variables for static files: `static_url_path` and `static_folder`. And your code mess these variables

```
Flask(static_folder=..., static_url_path=...)
```

---

`static_url_path` defines URL, not path to file on disk.

If you set

```
Flask(static_url_path="/home/maxloo/pyrest/static")
```

then URL in html has to start with `/home/maxloo/pyrest/static`

```
<img src="/home/maxloo/pyrest/static/temp/workdir/28d023bd-84e7-445a-8488-1e8aeb1fd50a/petri/LATEST.png"
```

but it will search images in local folder `static` (default is `Flask(static_folder="static")`)

---

`static_folder` defines local folder in which it has to search files

If you set

```
Flask(static_folder="/home/maxloo/pyrest/static")
```

then it searchs in local folder `/home/maxloo/pyrest/static` but url will have to start with default `/static`

```
<img src="/static/temp/workdir/28d023bd-84e7-445a-8488-1e8aeb1fd50a/petri/LATEST.png"
```

It will convert url `src=/static/<path>` to local path `/home/maxloo/pyrest/static/<path>` like in code

```
@app.router("/static/<path>")   # <static_url_path>/<path>
def static(path):
    return send_from_directory(static_folder, path)  # (static_dir, path)
```

---

So your code may need `static_folder=static_dir` instead of `static_url_path=static_dir` and `url = "/static/..."`

```
from flask import Flask

template_dir = "/home/maxloo/pyrest"
static_dir   = "/home/maxloo/pyrest/static"

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir, static_folder=static_dir)#, static_url_path='/static')

@app.route("/petri/<uuid>")
def getPetriFile(uuid):
    petri_folder = f'{static_dir}/temp/workdir/{uuid}/petri/'
    
    if not os.path.exists(petri_folder):
        Path(petri_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        # copy some file to folder
        shutil.copy(f'{static_dir}/LATEST.png', f'{petri_folder}/LATEST.png')
        
    # it has to start with `/static`
    image_url = f"/static/temp/workdir/{uuid}/petri/LATEST.png"
    
    return render_template("image.html", user_image=image_url)
```